# Passport submission for Canadian Visa

Tags: visas, canada

I am required to give the biometrics for the Canadian Visa. I live in Munich and the closest VAC is in Düsseldorf or Berlin. Is it possible to submit my passport at VAC while providing biometrics? Or do I need to wait until I have been asked to submit the passport?

Comment: This is offered as a comment, because I have no personal experience here. Assessing biometrics is part of the evaluative process. The application process is via e-docs and .pdfs; whoever is processing the applications will have no system to hold the physical passport of an applicant who hasn't yet been approved for a visa, and won't want it until approval has been decided. So the answer is no, you can't submit your passport until they ask for it, which will occur after (and, indeed, only if) they approve your application.